# Python Selenium Easy way to map out a ul with child elements and program it to select the correct one based on user input

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to make a python program that can select categories based on the ones a website provides. I would like the user to select a category before the program starts and selenium to automatically select it. For example we have

```
<ul>

    <li><a>Blah Parent</a>
        <ul>
            <a>Blah Child 1</a>
                <li><a>option 1</a></li>
                <li><a>option 2</a></li>
            <a>Blah Child 2</a>
                <li><a>option 3</a></li>
                <li><a>option 4</a></li>
            <a>Blah Child 3</a>
                <li><a>option 5</a></li>
                <li><a>option 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there an easy way to code this via python selenium or do i have to code it manually? I really dont want to code it manually because it would be thousands of child links that would take a lot of time.

Comment: what do you try to select? Using `xpath` you can select by text  - ie. `xpath('//a[contains(text(), "option 3"]'`. Because `xpath` is a string so you can format it as any other string - using `%`, `.format()` or `f""`

Comment: I know that. What I'm trying to avoid is making a line of code for each option. Were talking about thousands of categories here that is a lot of code to write. There has got to be an easier way.

Comment: but you said that you get category from user - so put it in xpath (using `%`, `.format()` or `f""`) and you will have only one line. ie. `'//a[contains(text(), "{}"]'.format(user_input)`

Comment: BTW: if you still need long code then write Python script to generate this code and you will not have to do it manually.